# How best to install a proxy for python selenium chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to install a proxy for python selenium chrome http and socks5 with authentification by login and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#proxies) for this.

```
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'https': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```